# Examples of sequences of positive terms $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_n^{1/n}\rightarrow l ~~\text{does not imply}~~ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\rightarrow l$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Give some examples of sequences of positive terms $\{a_n\}$ such that $$a_n^{1/n}\rightarrow l ~~\text{does not imply}~~  \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\rightarrow l$$

If $a_n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it can be shown that  $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\rightarrow l $ implies $a_n^{1/n}\rightarrow l$ by using log, a continuous function. This is Cauchy's second limit theorem. But I don't know how to show that its converse (that is the question I have written above) is not true.

Please help.

Comment: Don't write horrible things like "If $a_n > 0\forall n$". The $\forall$ symbol is NOT a drop-in replacement for the English words "for all". You should write this as "If $a_n > 0$ for all $n$" -- or, if you insist on using a symbolic quantifier you should follow the correct syntax for symbolic logic and write "If $\forall n(a_n>0)$" (there is some latitude in which punctuation you use, but the quantifier MUST come before the formula it ranges over), though that is kind of silly for such a short formula.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple example is $$ 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16, \ldots $$
or more formally $a_n = 2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$.

Then $(a_n)^{1/n} \to \sqrt 2$, but $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ alternates between $1$ and $2$, and therefore does not have a limit.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks. I would be happy if I have one more simple example like you have given.'

Comment: Or simply $\;\{x_n\}=\{1,2,1,2,1,2,...\}\;$ .

Comment: @Surb: No, it's alternately $2$ and $1/2$.

Comment: Could you pls justify how to see $(a_n)^{1/n} \to \sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\displaystyle a_n=3^{n+(-1)^n}$, so $\{a_n\}=\{3^0, 3^3, 3^2, 3^5, 3^4, 3^7, 3^6, \cdots\}$.

Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}3^{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}=3$,

but $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ does not exist, since $\displaystyle\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\begin{cases}3^3&\mbox {, if n is odd}\\3^{-1}&\mbox{, if n is even}\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the following sequence works:

$$a_1=l$$
$$a_n=\begin{cases}a_{n-1}*(l-1) \ \text{iff} \ n \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \\ a_{n-1}*\frac{l^2}{l-1} \ \text{iff} \ n \equiv 1 \pmod 2\end{cases}$$

Here, what I'm doing is alternating between a ratio of $l-1$ and $\frac{l^2}{l-1}$ so that after every $2$ terms, the ratio is $l^2$, but in between terms, the ratio alternates between $l-1$ and $\frac{l^2}{l-1}$. I am fairly certain this works for $l > 1$, but does not work once $l-1$ is negative because that contradicts that $\{a_n\}$ is positive.