# An example for a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive terms with $\lim_{n \to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=l<\infty $ but $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ has no limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can we suggest an example of sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive terms where $\lim_{n \to\infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ exists while not the limit $\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

Actually, I was looking for the converse of the statement

''If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive terms and
$\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l<\infty$, then $\lim_{n \to\infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=l$.''

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2202893/42969

Comment: And this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1784869/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $$a_n=\begin{cases}1&n\in 2\mathbb N\\ 2&n\in 2\mathbb N+1\end{cases}\ \ ?$$

---

The converse statement is true (i.e. for $(a_n)$ being a postive sequence, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } \ell\implies \sqrt[n]{a_n}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } \ell$ is true).

Comment: Oh....Nice....thank you....